# OCAML compilation error Out_of_memory

Tags: compilation, ocaml, out-of-memory

when I compile on my mutualized server the source of last version of OCaml ocaml-4.00.0, I have the following Out_of_memory error message:
"
Fatal error: exception Out_of_memory
Exit code 2 while executing this command:
  ../ocamlcomp.sh -c -g -warn-error A -w a -I camlp4/boot -I camlp4 -I stdlib -o camlp4/boot/camlp4boot.cmo camlp4/boot/camlp4boot.ml"

my initial bash command is : make world

Would anyody have an idea where this error might come from?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've compiled OCaml 4.00.0 many times recently, and I have some saved logs.  The exact failing command you give here appears at around the halfway point in the logs, which then go on to build the compiler successfully.  I would conclude from this that you're actually running out of memory.  I.e., that the compilation takes more memory than your system has available.  Is this possible?  (I don't know what you mean by a mutualized server.)

Comment: it is 1and1 mutualized server offer. But I had no difficulty compiling the 3.11 version of Ocaml on it

Comment: Well, it's possible that it takes more memory to compile the 4.00 compiler I guess.  Is it a 32-bit or a 64-bit system?

Comment: It is a known issue. See http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5633 . Though, the developers thinks it was already fixed. If you think the compiler eats all of your memory even in the release version of OCaml 4.00.0, add a comment to the entry or create a new one to ping them, with the information of your machine architecture and memory size.

Comment: well, I red the  caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5633  discussion and thought it had been fixed but, again, with the latest trunk source from Ocaml repository (http://caml.inria.fr/svn/ocaml/trunk/) I still get the exact same error message at the same point of "make world"

Comment: my serveur is a 32 bit system. My desktop (but irrelevant here I believe) is a 64

Comment: This really does look like PR 5633.  I've built OCaml 4.00.0 many times (like 20 or 30) over the last week and never seen memory exhaustion (mostly 32-bit builds, 8GB RAM).  It's possible I'm seeing a slow compile, though.  Basically I go get a cup of tea while building.  I agree with camlspotter, it might be good to re-open PR 5633 or report this as a new problem.

Comment: well actually, with the 3;12 version now I have a strange "toploop.cmi
is not a compiled interface" message when I compile the sources of the program I am currently working on ! so I am in the lurch (can't compile 4.00 and a lot of library incompatibilities when using OCaml's older versions)

Comment: This usually means you have an old cmi or cmo file from a previous compilation.  If I clear out everything and try again it usually works.

Comment: OK Jeffrey, thanks, this was it for my bug in 3.12. Still hoping to be able to load Ocaml 4.00 on my mutualized server....